# Pdf Byte Array From Java Server Calling from IOS Client App Using Swift. How to Show the as pdf at client side

Tags: ios, swift3

Actually i have one Java server. From my `IOS` App Calling the service and get the response with byte `array(pdf)` in the form `JSON` String.

I convert that `JSON` String to `NSDictionary` Using `NSJSONSerialization` method

and get the byte array using key as `NSMutableArray` 
then i converted `NSMutableArray` to `NSData` here is the code

```
let articleData: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary                    
let attachmentArray:NSMutableArray = articleData.valueForKey("attachment") as! NSMutableArray
let data:NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(attachmentArray)
```

from NSData i am trying to get pdffile using `writeToFile()` method but dam not able to View Pdf

Please help me!

Thank you

Comment: Show us your response?

Comment: As a result it showing the Blank pdf  In debug area it showing like failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.